# Is it possible to use one for loop for two string arrays in Java?

Tags: java, android, arrays, string, language-lawyer

Would it be possible to include String "arrayNames" in the for loop below like this: `for (String s:arrayLocations +String otherOne:arrayNames)`? I know this code is wrong, but this is just to get the idea across.

```
String[] arrayLocations = formattedLocations.split(",");
String[] arrayNames = formattedNames.split(",");

for(String s:arrayLocations)
{
   Toast.makeText(context, s, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
   Toast.makeText(context, toBeAdded, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

Comment: No, it's not possible using `for-each`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't iterate with  `foreach`, instead do a `for i`... (if both arrays are the same size...)

## Example:

```
for (int i = 0; i < arrayLocations.length; i++) {
    Toast.makeText(context, arrayLocations[i], Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    Toast.makeText(context, arrayNames [i], Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

Comment: yes they are the same length. Thanks, I'll accept your answer soon.

Answer (score 3):

No it's not possible, unless you create a new array consisting of the union of the two inputs. But then you essentially have three loops.

(Grammatically speaking, I can't see why syntax of the form `for (String s: arrayLocations, arrayNames)` couldn't be adopted into the language.)

One way to deal with this is to use a *function*:

```
private foo(String[] ss)
{
    for(String s:ss)
    {
       Toast.makeText(context, s, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
```

and call it twice, passing `arrayLocations`, then `arrayNames`. Arguably this is more extensible: perhaps `foo` could even become a member function of your `Toast` class, assuming you own it.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming the arrays are the same length,

```
String[] arrayLocations = formattedLocations.split(",");
String[] arrayNames = formattedNames.split(",");


for(int i = 0; i < arrayLocations.length; i++ )
{
   Toast.makeText(context, arrayLocations[i], Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
   Toast.makeText(context, arrayNames[i], Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You mean, you want to process the 0th element of arrayLocations along with the 0th element of arrayNames and so on? Not possible with the modern for loop, but quite standard with the traditional one.

```
if (arrayLocations.length == arrayNames.length) {
    for (int i = 0; i < arrayLocations.length; i++) {
        Toast.makeText(context, arrayLocations[i], Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        Toast.makeText(context, arrayNames[i], Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
```